# Bitbucket giving credit to wrong person for commits

Tags: git, bitbucket

I use Sourcetree and Bitbucket for version control. Whenever I commit and push from Sourcetree and look at it on Bitbucket under recent activity it shows that I made the commit. However, when I go to the commit page of the repository it says that a different employee made the commit. The person it is claiming made the commit instead of me used this computer before I did so I opened a Git command shell and typed git config user.name but it showed my name. I can't find any trace of his settings in Bitbucket's account settings page or Sourcetree's tools -> options menu and have no idea where else to look.

Comment: You might need to change the SSH key on your machine that Git uses when pushing and pulling.

Comment: I connect using HTTPS, where would I go to see if there is an SSH key hanging around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. My Email address is associated to his account.